# How to link to my apps in Google Play from my app?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

I have a small error that I can't seem to fix.

here's my code

```
public void moreApps(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri
            .parse("market://search?q=pub:dvir"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I simply want to link to my apps, which can be found here:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Dvir

What is the correct syntax?

Thanks in advance!

Dvir

Comment: `.parse("market://search?q=pub:Dvir"));` (notice the capital D) - it's case sensetive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://search?q=pub:Dvir"));
startActivity(intent);
```